# How to dispose objects with local variables within a class that implements IDisposable Interface

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

```
public class AnswerModel: IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposedValue;

        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string CodeSnippet { get; set; }
        public string AnswerBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }

        public string TimeStatus { get; set; }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
                }

                // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
                // TODO: set large fields to null
                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        // // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
        ~AnswerModel()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
            Dispose(disposing: false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }




  using (AnswerModel a = new AnswerModel())
                    {
                        a.Answer = answer.Answered;
                        a.AnswerBy = answer.AnswerBy;
                        a.DatePosted = answer.DatePosted;
                        a.CodeSnippet = answer.CodeSnippet;
                        answerModel.Add(a);
                    }
```

How to dispose the variables in the AnswerModel instance?

Does it happen by itself?

Comment: You don't. You only need to dispose non-memory resources or or resources owning native memory. Most regular objects only own managed memory, so they are handled by the garbage collector.

Comment: The int, bool and string are automatically taken of?

Comment: So even if I dont use the using braces it will be garbage collected?

Comment: @sly_Chandan yes.

Comment: Brilliant. I already knew the answer. I just wanted to confirm it. Thanks.

Comment: What about the destructor ? Is it necessary if I dont implement the IDisposable interface?

Comment: @sly_Chandan Answered about the destructor in my answer below.

Comment: c# does not have destructors, your `~AnswerModel()` is called a 'finalizer'. And that is only needed if your object owns unmanaged resources. They behave completely differently from c++ destructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a memory managed language. Objects created on the heap will get garbage collected automatically when there is no reference to the object and a GC cycle occurs (GC = garbage collector).

However there are some object that use resources outside the managed memory, For example File Streams, Web Connections or Database connection. They implement an interface called `IDisposable` with a function called `Dispose()`, that you can call when you finish using the resource.

In addition `~Object()` `Finalizers` are not good practice, because you don't know exactly when the GC frees the object, and it can create a load that you cannot control.

In conclusion you should implement `IDisposable` when your object uses outside resources that need to be `Disposed`, so you can free the resource when you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AnswerModel
    {
        private bool disposedValue;

        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string CodeSnippet { get; set; }
        public string AnswerBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }

        public string TimeStatus { get; set; }
    }

   ......somewhere within a function call.
     AnswerModel a = new AnswerModel()
     a.Answer = answer.Answered;
     a.AnswerBy = answer.AnswerBy;
     a.DatePosted = answer.DatePosted;
     a.CodeSnippet = answer.CodeSnippet;
     answerModel.Add(a);
```

Is this instance going to be garbage collected without any finalizers?

Comment: Yes, read my answer below